# Change "From" element in drupal mail

Tags: emails

While sending registration success e-mail in Drupal system, I want to update "from" element.

**Ex:**
My admin e-mail is "hello@gmail.com". 
While sending e-mail to user, I want to change it as "Myname <(hello@gmail.com)>"

Can we do it through hook_mail_alter?

I have tried below code. But din't work as expected.

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
 print_r($message); // I din't get any response here
}
```

Want to append Name before email ID.

**Edit**: `hook_mail_alter` its not triggering neither module nor `template.php`. Module is enabled. I have cleared cache too.

Existing comment : https://api.drupal.org/comment/59119#comment-59119

Comment: I think you need to make sure that hook_mail_alter is firing so you could print_r($message); die;

Comment: `hook_mail_alter` its not firing neither module nor `template.php` :(

Comment: after adding your hook you have to clear cache. also make sure that module is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily change the From with hook_mail_alter using '**from**'
key from $message.

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) { 
  $message['from'] = 'Your Name ('. $message['from'] . ')'; 
}
```

Also, Please check hook_mail function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7 which needs to be written for your module and then you need to call drupal_mail function.

hook_mail_alter is just for modifying the variables passed to drupal_mail.

Comment: `hook_mail_alter` - Its not firing in module as well as in `template.php` any idea why its not happening?

Comment: Have you written hook_mail and called drupal_mail function. I think either is missing in your code.

Comment: `hook_mail()` is not necessary, if the OP wants to alter emails sent from other modules.